# getting value of dojo NodeList inner elements

Tags: dojo, innerhtml, nodelist

I am building a configuration dialog using dojo that I later need to interrogate for user input. There are multiple rows in the dialog each with the same format and tags. Here is the html that I use to build each row.

```
html = '<div class="cfgtxtrow"> <label>Label:</label>
<input id="mac" type="hidden" name="mac" value="'+mac+'"/>
<input id="label" type="text" maxlength="6" name="label" value="'+labl+'"/>
</div>';
```

That part all works and I can see the data in Firebug on return.

I need to parse the values out and ultimately send them to the server using xhr. So I thought that I could use dojo query to get the nodelist and walk each node to get to the input values and build an associative array of them to send. I figured this to be much like validating the values programmatically.

I can see the innerhtml on each node (using dojo.query(".cfgtxtrow").forEach( function(node)) but cannot figure out how to programmatically (using dojo) get to the values on each node. I thought that I would be able to use dojo.byId or query on the Nodelist to get to its inner elements but I just get errors back.

I am beginning to suspect that my concepts are all wrong, as I thought this would be simple.

Here is what I ended up with..

```
dojo.query(".cfgtxtrow input").forEach( function(node)
{
    id = dojo.attr(node, "id" );
    console.debug( node );

    if( id == "mac" ) mac = dojo.attr( node, "value" ); // since mac comes first this is safe..
    if( id == "label" )
    {
        labl = dojo.attr( node, "value" );
        console.debug( mac );
        console.debug( labl );
        macLabels[mac] = labl;
    }
});
console.debug(macLabels[mac]);
// send the data via the xhrPut call..
```

I thought it should be simple and the dojo.attr call seems to do the job..

Is there a better way to do the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use the id attribute to identify multiple rows. There can be only one dom node with a certain id in an html document. Maybe that's the start of your problem?

So if you change your html as follows:

```
<div class="cfgtxtrow"> <label>Label:</label>
<input class="mac" type="hidden" name="mac" value="macValue"/>
<input class="label" type="text" maxlength="6" name="label" value="labelValue"/>
</div>​
```

Running this (quick & dirty) code on it

```
​require(['dojo/query'],function(query) {
    var macLabels = {};
    query('.cfgtxtrow').forEach(function(row) {
        var mac = query('.mac', row)[0].value;
        var label = query('.label', row)[0].value;
        macLabels[mac] = label;
    });
    console.log(macLabels);
});​​​​​​​​​
```

Will output this object on the console log: {macValue: "labelValue"}